# Android timer - 1 hour incorrect

Tags: android, timer

I hope someone can help. Im trying to set up a timer that times from the start of a game and displays this time. The problem is that the following section of code gives me the wrong time. Its in the wrong format, and is out by an hour.

```
private long startTime;
private SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss.SS");

//Constructor:
startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

public String getTime() {
long gameTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
final Date date = new Date(gameTime);
return timeFormat.format(date);
}
```

It consistently gives me the output of 01:00:03:203. The seconds are correct, but the 1 hour shouldn't be there, and for format is 3 decimal places instead of the two I thought I specified.

Thank you very much!

Comment: This can not be. Where do you take the `startTime` in your `getTime` method from? Is any communication with other server/ system involved?

Comment: The startTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); is performed in the class constructor. There is just a lot of other code that doesn't effect this problem so I left it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your date is epoch + gameTime. I think you're experiencing a daylight saving shift since the current DST in your location today doesn't match the DST at epoch.

Use a Calendar instead of a Date. Start with today and explicitly wipe out the hour, minute, etc. parts:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 3600000 + 60000 + 1000 + 1);

SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss.SS");

System.out.println(timeFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
```

The output for the above is: 01:01:01.01

http://ideone.com/DyQcl

Substitute the numbers I have above with `gameTime` and you're done.

Of course, this may not work once your millisecond ticks exceed the day boundary.

Comment: If I add the following code though:
`final Date startDate = new Date(startTime);
final Date currentDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
  
Log.d("TIME ERROR", "CURRENT TIME: "+ timeFormat.format(currentDate));
Log.d("TIME ERROR", "GAME TIME: " + timeFormat.format(startDate));`

I get the correct output of: GAME TIME: 17:12:58.231 CURRENT TIME: 17:13:05.775